# How to apply a condition to a subset of data? Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:3: unexpected symbol

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get rid of the first three characters of a string variable only for the first 18 observations (rows). How can I do this? I tried the code below but got an error: Error in parse(text = x) : :1:3: unexpected symbol

```
condition <- substring(Attend$"sample_label", 3) 
  filter_(Attend,condition) %>% slice(1:18)
```

Comment: Try `Attend$sample_label[1:18] <- substring(Attend$sample_label[1:18], 4)`

Answer (score 1):

please include more details. If I understand correctly, your dataframe is called Attend and the column of interest sample_label. If so, first of all, you do not need the quote marks (Attend$sample_label instead of Attend$"sample_label"). An easy way to do what you wish is the following:

```
library(dplyr)

Attend[1:18,]<-Attend[1:18,] %>%
                mutate(sample_label=substring(sample_label, first=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to remove first 3 characters for first 18 values in `sample_label` column.

```
Attend$sample_label[1:18] <- sub('.{3}', '', Attend$sample_label[1:18])
```